# Loading a resource (e.g. storyboard) in a Swift framework

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to make a framework that will bundle a storyboard. I have checked, and the created .framework includes my .storyboard file (as a `.storyboardc` file), and have gotten the framework to load the storyboard at runtime. However, this being a framework, I'd like for the code to be as versatile as possible, and I feel like my current solution is a little hacky. Currently, I'm loading the storyboard using the following code:

```
let mainBundlePath: String = NSBundle.mainBundle().resourcePath
let frameworkBundlePath = mainBundlePath.stringByAppendingPathComponent("Frameworks/AuthenticationManager.framework")
let frameworkBundle = NSBundle(path: frameworkBundlePath)
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Storyboard", bundle: frameworkBundle)
```

A couple of things I've noticed that could be gotchas:

- The path of the framework (`Frameworks/`) could, potentially, change in the future, and should not relied upon?
- The name of the framework could change, but without first getting the `NSBundle` of the framework there's no way of getting the product name?
- Frameworks aren't really bundles (?), so loading them as a bundle could have unforeseen consequences in the future?

There may be other issues, solutions to the above issues, or the above issues may not be issues after all, but I've not been able to think of them.

This question may be be more suited for [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/), but I felt it'd fit in well here, too. If it needs to be moved over there, feel free to do that or tell me to do it.

Comment: Hello, I know this topic is 4 years old.. I want to do pretty much same thing but I didn't find any tutorial or good example so I can learn from it. Can you (or anyone else) help me please ? just by giving me a hint or some links .. Thank you so much

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Here's a cleaner solution (no framework identifiers involved):

```
let storyboardName = "StoryboardName"
let storyboardBundle = NSBundle(forClass: self)
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: storyboardName, bundle: storyboardBundle)
```

If this code is not inside of a `static` method, use `YourClass.self` instead of `self`.

**Example for Swift 3:**

```
let storyboardBundle = Bundle(for: NumberPadViewController.self)
super.init(nibName: "NumberPadViewController", bundle: storyboardBundle)
```

Comment: Instead of let storyboardBundle = NSBundle(forClass: self), now it should be let storyboardBundle = NSBundle(forClass: className.self)

Comment: @azimov Well, it depends. If it's inside of a static method, `self` is enough. I added a little note to make things clearer. Thanks!

Comment: It's only a cleaner solution if this code is executing from within a class which is in the framework itself. If a "consumer" of the framework wanted access (and the access controls to the various classes were set to public), then the accepted answer is still the way to go.

Comment: @wuf810 You could still use in its `YourClass.self`  with a class from the framework, couldn't you?

Comment: This is not working for me. It's always crashing

Answer (score 61):

A framework (created from the "Cocoa Touch Framework" template) has a bundle identifier,
which is stored in the Info.plist of the generated framework bundle.

The bundle identifier is configured in the general target settings.
By default, it is `<organization prefix>.<framework name>`.

You can locate the framework using this identifier, for example:

```
let frameworkBundle = NSBundle(identifier: "com.duffy.AuthenticationManager")
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Storyboard", bundle: frameworkBundle)
```

Comment: Is there any way to access app's bundle from inside a framework. Using identifier might not be the feasible way as a framework might not know about app's bundle identifier.

Comment: @niks: `Bundle.main` is the main application bundle.

Comment: My hero! you saved me

Answer (score 8):

For Swift 3/4, it's now simply Bundle :

```
let bundle = Bundle(identifier: "com.myframework.id")
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "FrameworkMain", bundle: bundle)
```

Answer (score 6):

This is a much better way to load the bundle in Swift 3 without the need of passing a string that is much more likely to fail

```
let myBundle = Bundle(for: MyViewController.self)
let myStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "StoryboardName", bundle: myBundle)
```

Comment: If you have something like R.Swift, you can use the generated storyboard name to make it compile time safe