# iOS - access application bundle's resources from inside a framework

Tags: ios, json, iphone, xcode

GIVEN: I am implementing a framework that needs to search for all the JSON files that are in application bundle first; if there is nothing, then I load the JSON file from inside my framework

I have tried `Bundle` api like `bundleForClass:` using `UIApplication.self` as parameter but still accessing my own framework's bundle. Can someone suggest a way to achieve my demand?

Comment: OK I solved it... Just using `Bundle.main` and you will gain the access to the application bundle. Before this I just thought when in a framework, it is referring to the framework bundle because apple documentation says: `For a running app, the main bundle offers access to the app’s bundle directory. For code running in a framework, the main bundle offers access to the framework’s bundle directory.` Can anyone explain what exactly is the code running in a framework? Isn't it the one I write and pack as a dynamic framework?

Answer (score 1):

Basically you should add the option to pass the required bundle to search in as a parameter for your framework. You can also use the bundle unique identifier as described in below question, however it will bound your framework tightly to app which is not required I guess.

You can refer to similar question here [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24982848/loading-a-resource-e-g-storyboard-in-a-swift-framework)

Another idea I came across is to list all available bundles or frameworks you may use and filter your required bundle: [Check Apple's ref page](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFBundles/AccessingaBundlesContents/AccessingaBundlesContents.html)

But I guess the option 1 to specify the required bundle to search in as a parameter will be more convenient way.

```
func hasRequiredFiles(in bundle: Bundle) {
    // ... Your implementation
}
```

And the usage would be to call the function with `Bundle.main` from app.