# Get a framework's Bundle Identifier programmatically

Tags: swift, ios7

For logging purposes, I need to know the bundle identifier of the framework I am developing. I do not want to use a static string.

It is easy to access the bundle identifier of the app the framework is running in:

```swift
    var appBundleIdentifier = Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier
```

But I would like the bundle identifier of the framework like ("com.example.my-super-powerful-framework").

Comment: This may be what you are looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26633923/1187415. E.g. `let identifier = Bundle(for: AClassInYourFramework.self).bundleIdentifier`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access bundle identifier of an object like below;

```
let bundle = Bundle(for: AFrameworkClass.self)
let bundleId = bundle.bundleIdentifier
```

Comment: No need to instantiate an object: `let bundle = Bundle(for: AFrameworkClass.self)`